# Plotly Interactive Graph not working in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, plotly, ggplotly

In R, I have a dataframe "depins" of the following format, with the leftmost column having dates in a yearmon format:

[image]

I wanted to create an interactive graph using the ggplot2 and plotly packages, but when I try to interact/hover over any spot on the graph, it displays the **same date and value** (Jan 2004, 52) no matter where I interact with it. Does anyone perhaps know why the code below only displays the same date/value whenever I hover over it?

```
p<-
ggplot(depins, mapping=aes(x=Month, y=deposit_insurance))+
  geom_line(color="blue")+
  ggtitle("Frequency of 'deposit insurance' searches, 2004-present")+
  labs(x="Month", y="Frequency")

p<-ggplotly(p)
p
```

Comment: Convert your Month column to Date format if it is not `depins$Month <- lubridate::mdy(depins$Month, truncated = 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have converted your Month column to Date Format

```
library(zoo)
    
    depins <- data.frame(
      Month = c("Jan 2004", "Feb 2004", "Mar 2004", "Apr 2004", "May 2004", "Jun 2004","Jul 2004", "Aug 2004"),
      deposit_insurance = c(52,46,42,54,47,34,26,34)
      )
    
    depins$Month <- as.yearmon(depins$Month, format = "%b %Y")
    
    p<-
      ggplot(depins, aes(x=Month, y=deposit_insurance))+
      geom_line(color="blue")+
      ggtitle("Frequency of 'deposit insurance' searches, 2004-present")+
      labs(x="Month", y="Frequency")
      
    ggplotly(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you post data as an image, it is impossible to unambiguously diagnose issues related to data formatting, but that is likely the issue here. If we add modify your date with `lubridate::my()` it should work as expected.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(plotly)
 
d <- data.frame(month = paste(month.abb[1:8], "2004"), 
                deposit_insurance = c(52,46,42,54,47,34,26,34)) %>% 
  mutate(month = my(month)) # correct format of date column
  
p <- d %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = month, y = deposit_insurance)) +
  geom_line(color = "blue") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(month, deposit_insurance, sep = ":"))) + # added to show date in static view
  ggtitle("Frequency of 'deposit insurance' searches, 2004-present") +
  labs(x = "Month", y = "Frequency")

p
```

[image]

```r
# won't work in reprex
# ggplotly(p)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>